# How can I use measure tool with Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I didn't see any mention for measure tool in OL 3 API.
Is there an alternative / a way to use a measure tool (line & area) with OL 3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Measuring is easily accomplished with an `ol.interaction.Draw` on the application level. See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html for the official example demonstrating this. OpenLayers has functions for measuring on a sphere in the `ol/sphere` module:

```
import {getLength, getArea} from 'ol/sphere.js';

const lineStringLength = getLength(lineString);
const polygonArea = getArea(polygon);
```

Comment: distances at poles are less than what is seen on a planar map. the example does not count this. any help?

Comment: I just updated the example link and added example code to encourage use of the spherical `getLength()` and `getArea()` functions, which solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In openlayers 3 or newer versions, there is no inbuilt measure tool. You have to create it from scratch in OpenLayers. Go through following link to learn how you can create such tool.

[Create a DynamicMeasurement tool in OpenLayers to show measurements on labels that follow changing geometry](https://spatial-dev.guru/2021/09/05/create-a-dynamicmeasurement-tool-in-openlayers-to-show-measurements-on-labels-that-follows-2/)

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

link seems broken here is working link .

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/measure.html

Answer (score -2):

The latest example for ol-measurments: 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here. Please provide a more thorough answer which summarizes the content in the link, or the automated review process may result in deletion of this Answer.